# Php get String of .txt file by line

Tags: php, string, text

G'day everyone,
I have a .txt file and want to get line X from it.
Something like:

```
    "list.txt":
    Line1
    Line2
    Line3

    "file.php":
    $line = 1;
    echo "getLine("list.txt", $line)";
```

Basicly I want it to echo "Line2".
Any ideas what function I can use in "file.php"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a file with [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) creates an array so you should be able to access a line by index number

```
$file='list.txt';    
$lines=file( $file );
echo $lines[1], $lines[2], $lines[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php), see example below:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('example.txt');
$file->seek(1);
echo $file->current();
```

Comment: I like that - not used this before ut I like it!